# Cohomology of a quotient manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

Assume one has a finitedimensional vector space $V$ over the complex numbers and a discrete subgroup $G$ of translations on $V$, so that the quotient is a complex manifold $X=V/G$.

My question: can one express the cohomology group $H^1(X,\mathcal{O_X})$ in terms of the data $V$ and $G$?

Comment: Veen -- every automorphism of a vector space preserves the origin, so $G$ can't act freely unless it is trivial.

Comment: Sorry, the formulation was very misunderstanding...

Comment: A discrete subgroup $G$ of translations is actually a discrete subgroup of $V$ thought of as an abelian group.  Therefore it is free and hence is a lattice, thought not necessarily of maximal rank.  Let $W$ denote the complex span of $G$.  Choose a splitting $V = W \oplus U$.  Then $V/G = W/G \times U$, where $U \cong \mathbb{C}^p$ and $W/G$ is a complex torus (i.e., an abelian variety).

Comment: @José Why is $W/G$ automatically an abelian variety, i.e. why does it carry a non-degenerate Riemann form?

Comment: Ah, sorry.  Indeed it does not have to.  Let's stick with complex torus!


Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer has been corrected per Torsten's remark.

If $V/G = Y$ is a complex torus, i.e. $G$ has maximal rank, then Hodge symmetry says $H^1(Y,\mathcal O) = \overline{H^0(Y,\Omega)}$. But the cotangent bundle of $Y$ is trivial by translation on the group, so $H^0(Y,\Omega) = H^0(Y,\mathcal O) \otimes (T_0 Y)^\ast$ (the cotangent space at the identity). Now $T_0Y \cong V$, so $H^1(Y,\mathcal O) \cong \overline V^\ast$. If $Y=V/G$ is an algebraic torus, i.e. a product $(\mathbf C^\ast)^p$, then $H^1(Y,\mathcal O)$ is trivial. One way to see this is through the exponential sequence and the triviality of the Picard group of $Y$.

This also takes care of any product of complex tori, algebraic tori and affine spaces. But in general I see no reason that a quotient $V/G$ couldn't be a nontrivial extension of a complex torus by an algebraic torus. (In the algebraic setting this would be a semiabelian variety.) I don't know what happens to the cohomology then.

Comment: This is not quite the full story; you can have for instance $\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb C$ where the quotient is $\mathbb C^\ast$.